# How to animate ImageView in Android Widget most efficiently?

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

I'm trying to make animated widget for Android. I'm using Android Studio currently. It's a ImageView that rotates 30 times a second (30fps). I want to be able to change the rotating speed of the image. It's just like a clock (but turning much faster). I know, that this will pull battery energy extremely, but I think this is the only way to make it look like a "smooth" animated widget. Correct me if I'm wrong.

What is the most efficient way (for battery) to make something like this? I thought about following things like:
  - Rotating ImageView 30 times a second with a Timer in JAVA (best way?)
 
  - Trying to use a animated GIF (didn't got anything working yet - couldn't change the rotating speed that easy)

Any ideas?

Comment: You might consider taking a look at these libraries. https://github.com/shts/ClockAnimationView and https://github.com/alxrm/animated-clock-icon

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgP5fEAQboY

Comment: thanks - gonna check this :)